# Proof a different generalized derivative form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Prove that:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h,k\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k}.$$

The denominator is the issue. I thought of $u = h + k$ but that created an issue  for the limit bounds. I tried adding and subtraction $f(x)$ in the numerator but the denominator causes issues.

Only hints, please.